# How to get the field labels in trigger:

Tags: trigger

In following trigger.I need to get the labels for field labels in Opportunity Level:

> For example:

```
 Api name                                        Field Label

Client_Stability_Risk_Mitigation__c --->Client Stability Risk & Mitigation
Contract_Terms_Risk_Mitigation__c --->Contract Terms Risk & Mitigation
```

### etc.

```
   for(Opportunity op:opList){
 if(op.Client_Stability_Risk_Mitigation__c!=null &&  op.Top_Risk_Client_Stability__c){
       //I need field label of Client_Stability_Risk_Mitigation__c
        i++;
            op.Top_2_Risks__c=i+'.'+op.Client_Stability_Risk_Mitigation__c;

        }
        if(op.Contract_Terms_Risk_Mitigation__c!=null && 
  op.Top_Risk_Contract_Terms__c){
  //I need field label for Contract_Terms_Risk_Mitigation__c
               if(op.Top_2_Risks__c!=null){
               i++;
                   op.Top_2_Risks__c=op.Top_2_Risks__c+'\n'+i+'.'+op.Contract_Terms_Risk_Mitigation__c;
               }
           }}
```

Comment: -1 for not demonstrating any research efforts, please make sure you do so prior to posting, you have been a member for quite some time now and your post history does not do you much favor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get it from apex describe calls - [DescribeSObjectResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm#apex_Schema_DescribeSObjectResult_fields):

To get Account Name:

```
Schema.SObjectType.Account.fields.Name.getLabel()
```

In your example:

```
Schema.SObjectType.Opportunity.fields. Client_Stability_Risk_Mitigation__c.getLabel()
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get this information with the Describe API. For example,

```
String fieldLabel = Opportunity.Client_Stability_Risk_Mitigation__c.getDescribe().getLabel();
```

There are many ways to invoke the Describe API; see [DescribeFieldResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm#apex_methods_system_fields_describe) and [DescribeSobjectResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm#apex_methods_system_sobject_describe) for more details and examples.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this using describe cls.

```
 for(Opportunity op:opList){
if(op.Client_Stability_Risk_Mitigation__c!=null &&  op.Top_Risk_Client_Stability__c){
    //I need field label of Client_Stability_Risk_Mitigation__c
    i++;
    op.Top_2_Risks__c=i+'.'+Opportunity.Client_Stability_Risk_Mitigation__c.getDescribe().getLabel();

}
if(op.Contract_Terms_Risk_Mitigation__c!=null && 
   op.Top_Risk_Contract_Terms__c){
       //I need field label for Contract_Terms_Risk_Mitigation__c
       if(op.Top_2_Risks__c!=null){
           i++;
           op.Top_2_Risks__c=Opportunity.Top_2_Risks__c.getDescribe().getLabel();+'\n'+i+'.'+Opportunity.Contract_Terms_Risk_Mitigation__c.getDescribe().getLabel();
       }
   }}
```